# selectionChanged event in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ag-grid

How do I get `selectionChanged` event in ag-grid javascript? I mean I need to perform some operation while user checked `checkbox` in `ag-grid` so I need to get an event in jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Define your function of what you need to happen when user changes a selection:

```
function doSomething (eventData){
    console.log("user changed the selection range!")
    console.log(eventData)
}
```

Then you pass this function to the gridOptions:

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    selecitonChanged: doSomething,
    ...
}
```